# Epub reader horizontal Android

Tags: java, android, webview, epub

How to make a epub reader in which a html page is divided into several screens? I want to get the effect reading page by page, and browse pages horizontally rather than vertically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CSS3 columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) to create pages, then implement swipe between them.

Existing javascript solutions:

- [Monocle](https://github.com/joseph/monocle) - huge and powerful library.
- [Swipe Columns](https://github.com/manifestinteractive/swipe-columns-jquery-plugin) - less complicated and easier to understand. Works slow on some devices though.

Also, maybe you'd be interested in some full-featured readers like [FBReader](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ). They use native rendering instead of WebView.